# Laravel Ajax live search relationship

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

Laravel ajax live search does not work. In the console browser, he writes a 500 error. The problem is this relationships. If I do not use it relationship, the ajax live sarch is work. How do I edit my code to work? 
Here the code, to be precise:

```
$contract->typzakazky->nazov_typu.
```

My model:

```
public function typzakazky()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ContractsType','contracts_type_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    return view('contracts.index');

}
public function search(Request $request)

{

    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $output = "";

        $contracts = DB::table('contracts')->where('nazov', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . "%")->get();

        if ($contracts) {

            foreach ($contracts as $key => $contract) {

                $output .= '<tr>' .

                    '<td>' . $contract->poradove_cislo . '</td>' .

                    '<td>' . $contract->nazov . '</td>' .

                    '<td>' . $contract->typzakazky->nazov_typu. '</td>' .

                    '<td>' . $contract->datumodovzdania. '</td>' .

                    '</tr>';

            }


            return Response($output);


        }


    }
}
```

View:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
        $value=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
            data:{'search':$value},
            success:function(data){
                $('tbody').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
</script>
```

How to use it properly relationship in ajax? Very thank you.

Comment: do you want to fetch data in chain relation..?